# Seleccionar registros repetidos en MySQL para determinados datos con HAVING y COUNT()

Tags: mysql

buenos días, necesito seleccionar registros repetidos para determinados datos específicos y aun no encuentro la manera de formular la consulta, podrían ayudarme?

Tengo la siguiente tabla `archivoscompartidos` donde tengo archivos que son compartidos por dos o mas personas:

```
id_archivo  id_p
1           1
1           2
2           2
2           3
1           3
3           2
3           4
4           1
4           2
4           3
```

Quisiera seleccionar solo el o los archivos que son compartidos por dos personas especificas, por ejemplo `id_p=2` y `id_p=3` pero no si son compartidos por mas personas.

Por ejemplo si selecciono los archivos de la persona **2** me retorna 4 resultados.

`select id_archivo from archivoscompartidos where id_p=2; #1,2,3,4`

Si selecciono los archivos de la persona **3** obtengo tres resultados:

`select id_archivo from archivoscompartidos where id_p=3; #1,2,4`

Hasta aquí bien, pero los archivos *1* y *4* son compartidos por tres personas, así que necesito ignorarlos. Buscando por Internet encontré muchos ejemplos de la clausula `having` junto con `count()` pero aun así no logro lo que quiero conseguir.

Por ahora tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
select id_archivo, count(id_p) as p from archivoscompartidos where id_p=2 and id_archivo in (select id_archivo from archivoscompartidos where id_p=3) group by id_archivo having count(id_p)<3;
```

Pero lo que obtengo es:

```
id_archivo  p
1           1
2           1
4           1
```

Claramente, algo no estoy entendiendo, necesito que me retorne solo el `id_archivo` *2*.
¿Podrían orientarme? Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Debes cambiar el group by de la siguiente manera:

```
select id_archivo, count(id_p) as p from archivoscompartidos where id_p=2 and 
       id_archivo in (select id_archivo from archivoscompartidos where 
       id_p=3) 
group by id_p having count(id_p);
```

Debe hacer el group by por el contenido del count